# How to sum elements in haskell (odd and divided by 3)

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write function in haskell , I want that function to sum only odd and divided by 3 elements from list.

my code is :

```
nieplist n = (n/2 > 1) && mod n 3 == 0
niepdodlist xs = sum $ filter nieplist xs
```

I think that everything should work , first i'm checking if number from list is odd after that i want to check if it's divided by 3. (number module 3 always will be 0 )

When i try to write:

```
*Main>niepdodlist [1,2,3,6]
```

result is

```
<interactive>:220:1:
No instance for (Integral a0) arising from a use of `niepdodlist'...


<interactive>:220:14:
No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal `1'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous...
```

The Result Should be:

```
*Main>niepdodlist [3,6,3]
>9
```

Solution (thanks to @kqr)

```
nieplist n = odd n && mod n 3 == 0
niepdodlist xs = sum $ filter nieplist xs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for odd integers, this: `(n/2 > 1)` is probably wrong. You might want to try replacing it with `odd n`. It just happens that `odd` is a function in the standard library!

The reason you get such a scary-looking error is because the division operator (`/`) can only be used with fractional numbers, but the modulo function (`mod`) can only be used with integral numbers. So the type checker gets confused about whether you want `n` to be an integer or a float.

But keep in mind that based on your description of the problem, the result of

```
niepdodlist [3,6,3]
```

should be 6, not 12! Since 6 is an even number it doesn't count towards the sum.

Comment: thank you very much my friend , that helped ;)

But you are right , it's 6 , how to count towards the sum ?
Oh no , I'm so stupid. It's okay sorry .
I will write solution in my question.

Answer (score 1):

For the error, the function `(/)` is defined as `(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`, but the function `mod` as `mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`. As you can see, one uses fractionals and the other uses integrals. One solution would be using div or quot (you can infix using backticks).

> 5 `div` 2 = 2

For the logic, to test if a number is odd you should only test `n % 2 == 0`, `(n/2 > 1)` does not accomplish the same result (any number greater than 3 will do it!).

This function is also a good example for list comprehensions.

> niepdodlist xs = sum [x | x <- xs, odd x, x `mod` 3 == 0]